# how to create gradient function for tf.bincount in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

i tried to use `optimizer.compute_gradients` to calculate a function that has tf.bincount as one of steps, the error message is there is no registered gradient for this function in tensorflow, as shown below

"No gradient defined for operation 'Bincount' (op type: Bincount)"

I then registered my own gradient for this ops,

```
@ops.RegisterGradient("Bincount")
def _Bincount_grad(op, grad):
    Tem=tf.constant([1],dtype=tf.float32)
    Bin_index = tf.fill(tf.shape(op.inputs[0]), Tem)
    Mul_index=tf.fill(tf.shape(op.inputs[1]),Tem)
    Const_index=tf.fill(tf.shape(op.inputs[2]),Tem)
    return Bin_index,Mul_index,Const_index'
```

But it keep on throwing error message like

```
ValueError: No attr named '_XlaCompile' in name: "Bincount"
op: "Bincount"
input: "Const"
input: "mul"
input: "Relu"
attr {
  key: "T"
  value {
    type: DT_FLOAT
  }
}
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:
 Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for 'gradients/Bincount_grad/Fill' 
(op: 'Fill') with input shapes: [2], [1].
```

basically the output should be a list of 1 with length of input value group
it would be helpful if someone could provide some hint on this subject, i am relative new to tensorflow